# Required IAM roles to set service account to an existing scheduled query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to et service account to an existing scheduled query but this command failed. What are required IAM roles to do it?

Note that I already have `roles/bigquery.admin`.

```
bq update --transfer_config \
--update_credentials \
--service_account_name=bigquery-scheduled-query@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
projects/xxx/locations/us/transferConfigs/xxxxx
Bigquery service returned an invalid reply in update operation: 
Error reported by server with missing error fields. Server returned:
 {'error': {'code': 403, 'message': 'The caller does not have permission', 
'status': 'PERMISSION_DENIED'}}.
```

Comment: You have the `roles/bigquery.admin` means YOU is the user who run the bq update command? What are YOUR other roles? And what are the role of bigquery-scheduled-query SA? Can it run the query?

Comment: Yes I am using my personal account. Then I am asking what IAM roles except roles/bigquery.admin do I need.

Comment: What roles are assigned to the account executing this command? What roles are assigned to the service account that you are impersonating (`bigquery-scheduled-query`) for the project in the error message. Is everything in the same project? Edit your question with details.

Comment: These APIs must be enabled to impersonate a service account: `iamcredentials.googleapis.com` and `cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For setting a service account into a component, the requester must have the permission `iam.serviceAccounts.actAs`. This permission is contained into the role `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser`.

Thus, grant your user account the `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser` role and it should work.

Comment: Thanks I confirmed this works fine. I tested it as follows. (1) Created a new service account. (2) Attach BigQuery Admin and Service Account User IAM Roles to the account. (3) Enable the account credential by `gcloud auth activate-service-account  test-user@xxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=/path/to/key/file.json` (4) run "bq update" command.

Comment: Thanks, Guillaume and Yohei. Is there a way to check the existing service account associated with a scheduled query? The `service_account_name` field isn't in its `transfer_config` object.